# Setting a texture paint for GENERAL PATH

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to set texture for the path I have created.
If I am not mistaking the bits are delegated in the following way, first 8=alpha, second 8=blue, third 8=green, third 8=blue

For experimenting I set the color to red but it is not red when I set the value of red to 255 and the others to 0;
It does become red when I set red to 255 and green to 255 too.

Why is the value of "col" always negative?

I can not understand that.
Please help me.

```
public class main {
 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }});
         
    }
    static acer panel0;
    private static void createGUI() {
        panel0=new acer();
        JFrame jj=new JFrame();
        jj.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jj.setSize(900,700);
        jj.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        jj.add(panel0);
        jj.pack();
        jj.setVisible(true);
         
    }
 
}
 
 
class acer extends JPanel{
     
    BufferedImage image1=new BufferedImage(100,100,BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
    int b=0;
    int g=255;
    int r=255;
    int a=0;
    int col=(a<<24)|(b<<16)|(g<<8)|r;    
 
     
    acer(){
 
         
        for(int i0=0;i0<60;i0++) {
            for(int i1=0;i1<60;i1++) {
                image1.setRGB(i0,i1,-col);
            }
        }
 
         
        this.setOpaque(true);
        this.setBackground(Color.red);
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900,700));
    }
 
     
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
         
        int[] x2P= {640,690,740,890,740};
        int[] y2P= {550,400,550,600,650};
         
        GeneralPath path8=new GeneralPath(Path2D.WIND_EVEN_ODD,x2P.length);
        path8.moveTo(x2P[0], y2P[0]);
         
        for(int i=1;i<x2P.length;i++) {
            path8.lineTo(x2P[i], y2P[i]);
             
        }
        path8.closePath();
         
        TexturePaint texture0=new TexturePaint(image1,new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,10,10));
         
        g2d.setPaint(texture0);
        g2d.fill(path8);
   
    }
  
}
```

Comment: In a paintComponent method, the first line should always be `super.paintComponent(g);`.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/ for a full explanation.  As for `col` being negative, try printing it in hex:  `System.out.printf("%08x%n", col);`

Comment: I changed the drawing JPanel background to white so I could see the image.  The image appears in the lower right corner.  Red (255, 0, 0) comes out as yellow, while red (255, 255, 0) comes out as red.  Please update your question to explain in much more detail what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Cross posted: https://coderanch.com/t/749590/java/Setting-texture-paint-GENERAL-PATH